# Set .java as default file extension in vscode?

Tags: java, default, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the default language for new files? By default when we create a new file it is set as "txt"extensions.I want that ".java" as default file extension
I tried using "files.defaultLanguage":"java"
But this is setting file extension as ".class" instead of ".java"

How do I set ".java" as a default file extension?

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue about VSCode. In fact, it really has chosen the 'Java' as the file type. But you can find the filename extension list of 'Java' type: *.class, *.java, *.jav, *.java, *.jav. So, you only can modify it manually for now. And I have put a feature request in Github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105463